# Bash Array Feature or Bug?

Tags: bash

While attempting to debug a job submission script, I ended up narrowing down the bug to this:

```
    [testuser@bes ~]$ var=( 1 foo1*bar4 echo 1*4=4 )
    [testuser@bes ~]$ echo "${var[@]}"
    1 foo1*bar4 echo 1*4=4
    [testuser@bes ~]$ cd /data/testuser/jobs/example/a16162/
    [testuser@bes a16162]$ var=( 1 foo1*bar4 echo 1*4=4 )
    [testuser@bes a16162]$ echo "${var[@]}"
    1 foo1-bar4 foo1*bar4 echo 1*4=4
    [testuser@bes a16162]$
```

That is an uncut transcript of a fresh bash session.    Anyone have any idea how that one works?  Is this some archaic feature of bash that I've never heard of before, or just a really weird bug?

Versions (yes I know it's out dated):

```
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Linux bes 2.6.18-194.11.3.el5 #1 SMP Mon Aug 30 16:19:16 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

EDIT: This is for something that needs to process a user-passed array, and I'd rather use this method than a triplet of rather awkward `awk` hacks.  They're trivial "extract element 2" sorts of things, which is why using the array seems nicer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Globs are still globbed when the array is formed. If you don't want this then you need to quote or escape them.

```
$ var=( 1 "foo1*bar4" echo "1*4=4" )
```

Comment: !!!! Why did I not think of that; I knew it had to be folder-dependent, but somehow missed that.  Thankyou much.  I don't think I can quote `var=( $l )`, so I guess I'll just use `cut`.

Comment: @zebediah49 certainly you can quote `var=( "$l" )`... unless what you really want is to string-split but not glob-expand `$l`? That's possible too, but you need to tell us what you want before we can tell you how to do it.

Comment: I vaguely touched on it, but I want to split the string, without anything else happening.  Specifically, I need `${var[0]}`, `${var[1]}`, and `${var[@]:2}`.  `awk` will do this, just somewhat awkwardly.

Answer (score 1):

What does `ls /data/testuser/jobs/example/a16162/foo1*` reveal?

You can disable filename globbing with `set -f` and re-enable it with `set +f`